# Node, how to send result back to client from nested HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rancher

I'm using ReactJS to run my front-end and using Express for my back-end. I want to make a get request to my back-end using the "/paas" path to get a listing of all of my pods that are running inside my namespace in Rancher(Kubernetes).

The back-end then needs to be able to make an https request to my Rancher API endpoint and return the result to the front-end. I can make the successful call to Rancher API and see the data print to the screen on my back-end but I get lost when trying to send this data to the front-end and console log it out inside the browser.

Due to "pre-flight" errors, I can't just make a direct call to the Rancher endpoint inside of my App.js file. [More info on this here](https://forums.rancher.com/t/request-from-react-app-to-rancher-api-returning-401/14449). So I need to go the custom back-end route. I any case, it seems like this should be pretty straightforward. Any guidance would be appreciated.

App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

function App() {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fecthPods = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/paas`)
        console.log(response.data)
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response) {
          // Not in the 200 response range
          console.log(err.response.data)
          console.log(err.response.status)
          console.log(err.response.headers)
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`)
        }
      }
    } 
    fecthPods()
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Back-end server.js:

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import https from "https"
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.use("/data", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ name: "Minion", favFood: "pizza"})
})

app.get("/paas", bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {

    const options = {
        hostname: "k8.fqdn.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/k8s/clusters/c-wwfc/v1/pods/mynamespace",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer token:12345"
        }
      }
    
    const request = https.get(options, (res) => {
        let responseBody = ""
        res.setEncoding("UTF-8")
        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            console.log("---chunk", chunk.length);
            responseBody += chunk;
          });
        res.on("end", () => {
            let json = JSON.parse(responseBody)
            // console.log(responseBody)
            console.log("Response finished");
            res.json({data: responseBody})
        });
    });
    request.end()
    res.json({ status: "complete", data: request.data})
})

app.listen(3001) 
console.log("backend up on 3001")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of errors on your backend code.

First, you are naming the `res` variable for the express middleware and also for the response received by the `https` module. In this way, you lose the possibility to access to the `express response object` in the `on.('end')` callback.

Secondly, you are triyng to respond to the client multiple times (inside the `on.('end')` callback and also directly inside the express middleware with the instruction  `res.json({ status: "complete", data: request.data})`. Also, consider that the code you wrote is repliyng to the client before the call to  the k8s cluster is made. And the response will always be a JSON with this data: `{ "status": "complete", "data": undefined}`.

To fix all, try with this code (I will try to comment all edits):

```
app.get("/paas", bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {

    const options = {
        hostname: "k8.fqdn.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/k8s/clusters/c-wwfc/v1/pods/mynamespace",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer token:12345"
        }
      }
    
    const k8sRequest = https.get(options, (k8sResponse ) => { // as you can see I renamed request and res to k8sRequest and k8sResponse, to avoid loosing the scope on req and res express middleware variables
        let responseBody = ""
        res.setEncoding("UTF-8")
        k8sResponse.on("data", (chunk) => { // here use k8sResponse to collect chunks
            console.log("---chunk", chunk.length);
            responseBody += chunk;
          });
        k8sResponse.on("end", () => { // here use k8sResponse again
            let json = JSON.parse(responseBody)
            // console.log(responseBody)
            console.log("Response finished");
            res.json({ status: "complete", data: responseBody}) // here use the express res variable, to reply to the client. 
        });
    });
    k8sRequest.end() // here use the k8sRequest variable to make the https call to the k8s cluster
    // here I deleted  the res.json instruction
})
```

The above code should just works. Anyway, I suggest you using `axios` also with your backend service. You are already using it with `React`, so you know how to use it. The syntax is minimal and easier and you can use the async/await approach.

Axios solution:

```
  import axios from "axios"

  app.get("/paas", bodyParser.json(), async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const url = 'https://k8.fqdn.com/k8s/clusters/c-wwfc/v1/pods/mynamespace'
    
      const k8sResponse = await axios.get(url, headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer token:12345"
      })
    
    
      res.json({ status: "complete", data: k8sResponse.data })
    } catch (e) {
       res.json({status: "error", data: e.response.data})
    }
    
            
})
```

You should wrap your `axios` call inside a `try/catch` block to properly handle errors like you are doing with your `React` implementation. Error handling should be also implemented if you still want you the native node.js `https` module

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and education. I'm still green with React and Node. The only tweak I made was changing `res.setEncoding("UTF-8")` to `k8sResponse.setEncoding("UTF-8")`. Using your example I was also able to get `Axios` version working in my backend! Just to confirm `res` should be scoped to `express` and if we need to make other `http` calls from inside `express` then we should try to use different names for them. Like you did in my case with `(k8sRequest, k8sResponse)`

Comment: I mean, it's up ro you. Code can be structured in infinite ways. But in general, naming to different variables with the same name in the same scope it's not a great idea in any programming launguage, unless you know what you are doing